# What happens to existing objects when you declare prototype inheritance?

Tags: javascript, object, methods, prototype

```js
//debugger;

function User(email,name) {
    this.email = email;
    this.name = name;
    this.online = false;
}

User.prototype.login = function() {
    this.online = true;
    console.log('this.name is now online');
}

function Admin(...args) {
    User.apply(this, args);
    this.title = 'admin';
}

const admin1 = new Admin('admin@admin.com', 'josh');

Admin.prototype.deleteUser = function() {
    console.log('deleted user');
}

Admin.prototype = Object.create(User.prototype);

const admin2 = new Admin('admin2@admin.com', 'barry');

console.log(admin1); //admin1 will have the deleteUser() method in its prototype, and DIDN'T update after Admin inherited the User prototype 

console.log(admin2); //admin1 will have the login() method and NOT deleteUser()
```

Why did admin1's prototype update when I made the deleteUser() method, but why did it not update at all when I inherited User.prototype?

Comment: `( admin1 instanceof User ) === false`, so your prototype chain is broken somewhere.

Comment: Given it's now 2022, have you considered using ES `class` definitions instead of the old-school `function Constructor`-style?

Answer (score 0):

I realized that when I declared deleteUser() I was simply adding onto the prototype object of Admin, but when I inherited User's prototype I completely reassigned Admin's prototype. For example, if I declared **x = {a:1}** I could do **x.b = 2** and then **x is now {a:1, b:2}**. BUT if I do **x = {a:1}** and then right after do **x = {b:2}**, it completely replaces the value of x, not add onto it.